# Sort an array of arrays by the first elements in the nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

This is an incredibly basic question that I could do in Python in a matter of seconds- but I'm new to Javascript and maybe I just don't know the nomenclature for the language, but my research hasn't quite answered it.

I'm making an API call; and in response I've got:

```
let unordered_ranges = [[
    [1461913200000, 57, 69],
    [1380006000000, 75, 79],
    [1321344000000, 78, 79],
    [1276585200000, 69, 75],
    [1252998000000, 68, 76],
    [1234512000000, 79, 81],
    [1423814400000, 77, 78],
    [1489820400000, 69, 79]
]];
```

The first element in the nested arrays are timestamps in milliseconds. How do I sort the parent array chronologically using the nested timestamps?

So far I've got:

```
let ranges= unordered_ranges.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a > b
});
```

I understand .sort() is lexicographic; so I need to pass my own function to sort it; however this function doesn't quite do it.

Comment: This isn't quite a nested array, it's an array with a single object in it, that object having properties 0-9 which are arrays.  In javascript object keys cannot be ordered.  You might want to parse the response from your api into a true array.

Comment: The `Array.prototye.sort` callback should return an integer, typically in the range of `-1` to `1`. You are returning a boolean

Comment: Please show how the expected output will look like

Comment: Your example code is now no longer valid JavaScript. What do you **actually** have?

Comment: Updated again... When I print to console, this is exactly what I see.

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to access the first array entry (since you only have one) and then [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) with a standard numeric comparator using the first array item of each entry.

```js
let unordered_ranges = [[
    [1461913200000, 57, 69],
    [1380006000000, 75, 79],
    [1321344000000, 78, 79],
    [1276585200000, 69, 75],
    [1252998000000, 68, 76],
    [1234512000000, 79, 81],
    [1423814400000, 77, 78],
    [1489820400000, 69, 79]
]];

let ranges = unordered_ranges[0].sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])

console.info(ranges)
```

---

To explain the comparator, it's best to read the documentation...

> If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If `a` and `b` are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort `a` to an index lower than `b`, i.e. `a` comes first.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave `a` and `b` unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort `b` to an index lower than `a`, i.e. `b` comes first.
> - `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements `a` and `b` as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize. I'd misrepresented my data set above. It is an array of arrays.